# google SpreadsheetのIMPORTXML関数の文字化け

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome, google-spreadsheet

Shift-JISのページをIMPORTXML関数で情報取得しようとすると
日本語は文字化けしてしまいます。
SpreadsheetがUTF-8正直使えない関数だなと思いました。

何かしらの回避方法は無いのでしょうか？
ShitJis→UTF-8に変換するような方法とか
(apps scriptは多少使えるのでそれで出来ないかと)

Comment: 自作関数でshitjisに対応するようなスクリプトが組めない・・・・

Comment: 何方も分からないのですね。やはり難しい内容なのでしょうか？